# Add google play service library under java build path

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am using map view. I have added Google play service library to my project as dependency project and it works fine. But if I try to import it into libs folder of my project and add it under java build path, it gives error.

Can I add google play service library under java build path? If no, why?

error showed in 
console :

```
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] '\\Dragon\d\Android\eclipse'
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.b: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Fragment getParentFragment()' in class android.app.Fragment
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService$a: can't find referenced class android.app.AppOpsManager
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService$a: can't find referenced class android.app.AppOpsManager
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.games.internal.PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1: can't find referenced method 'android.view.Display getDisplay()' in class android.view.View
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.an$2: can't find referenced method 'void evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback)' in class android.webkit.WebView
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gp: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getDefaultUserAgent(android.content.Context)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gp: can't find referenced method 'void setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gv: can't find referenced method 'void evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback)' in class android.webkit.WebView
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: there were 11 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] Warning: there were 6 unresolved references to program class members.
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-03-17 13:10:28 - LifeScience]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

**Edit**

I have added **dontwarn** to my proguard.txt file and now I am able to export my application.

**proguard-project.txt**

```
    -keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
```

I have searched on google but the concept of **dontwarn** is not clear to me.Can anyone explain me what **dontwarn** does and is it safe to use while obfuscation?

Comment: no you cant......because its a whole project, not just libs. why you want to add it to libs?

Comment: If i use it as external project, it gives problem while creating proguard.

Comment: just do some config to your proguard

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the `google-play-services-lib` as a library-project. They updated the **SDK**. There are several tutorials around. For **Eclipse** it is easy:

```
Right click project -> properties -> Android
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Proguard configuration for google play service

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Source : [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import google play services as a project. Then go to your projects properties, then to Android build path (where you pick your sdk versions) then click add to the google play services project. Clean and Build it.

Comment: Problem is while creating proguard. I have successfully added google play service to my project, but after adding if I try to export my project, I am getting the error which I have mentioned above.